# Convert input stream into file android

Tags: android, file, inputstream

in my application i am using below code that returns input stream

```
QBContent.downloadFileById(fileId, new QBEntityCallback<InputStream>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(final InputStream inputStream, Bundle params) {
    long length = params.getLong(Consts.CONTENT_LENGTH_TAG);
    Log.i(TAG, "content.length: " + length);

    // use inputStream to download a file
}

@Override
public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {

}
}, new QBProgressCallback() {
@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(int progress) {

}
});
```

now i want to covert input steam into file then want to do two things with that file
 1. how can i save it to user's phone storage
 2. save it temporarily and display's it in pdf viewer using intent
 note: returned file will be in pdf formal

Comment: Did you ever settle on a correct solution?

Answer (score 4):

You did not mentionned if you wanted to store in external or internal storage, I wrote this example for internal storage

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line).append('\n');
}

try {
  OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("file.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
  outputStreamWriter.write(total.toString());
  outputStreamWriter.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
```

Don't forget to use `try/catch` and close what needs to be closed

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to store `InputStream` in File.

But you need to pass file path and where you want to store file  in storage.

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    // read this file into InputStream
    inputStream = new FileInputStream("/Users/mkyong/Downloads/file.js");
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    System.out.println("\nDone!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```